# How reliable is Rails' ActionPack remote_ip for requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, network-programming, geolocation

I have always been leery of methods that return public ip addresses.  They seem to be generally faulty unless you use an external service such as whatismyip.com.

**How reliable is Rails remote_ip method at determining the external public ip 100% of the time?** https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb

I just discovered that the issue I was fighting was CloudFlare and it having a different header available of `CF-Connecting-IP`.  It appears that I have to yank that out via something along the lines of `(headers["CF-Connecting-IP"] || remote_ip)` in order to overcome this particular situation.

So it appears that either I need to monkey patch `remote_ip` or take this into consideration without drying up my code everywhere.

Comment: What are you going to do? What should it be reliable for?

Comment: simply detecting remote ip of clients using a webapp.  The goal is to reliably ascertain timezones based on ip.

Comment: Aren't you detecting your own ip instead of the remote one withbthat service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remote_ip comes from HTTP request header, so anyone who know how to change it can change remote_ip address. also it is possible to use proxies and change address in that way. you can use it for geolocation or something like that, but i think its not good for blacklist or white-lists.

Comment: Ended up having to extract the ip from the appropriate headers: `CF-Connecting-IP` and `X-Forwarded-For`

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the current implementation of `remote_ip`, and I had to rework it to correctly handle `X-Forwarded-For` (especially if the request contains more than one `X-Forwarded-For` header). It sounds like you might want to submit a pull request that makes the method check the `CF-Connecting-IP` header as well. Lastly, you might need to change the app server you use in production, since some of them can [ignore repeated request headers](http://andre.arko.net/2011/12/26/repeated-headers-and-ruby-web-servers/).

Comment: I'm in the same position as the poster, and I'm just asking to see if it's worth the effort: Is it likely that handling of vendor specific headers like that actually gets added to the rails source?

Comment: It would be extremely trivial to write your own middleware that handles remote_ip and insert that middleware instead of the one that ships with ActionPack. I suggest doing that to try things, and submitting a pull request if it's useful for you.